# Reorder few columns only out of hundreds

Tags: r

What is the most efficient way to reorder columns for data frames with hundreds even thousands of columns?

The following is tried and it works, however I am looking for an optimal function.

`dput(names(df1))` to dump all column names and used in the following step

swapped columns with `df1[c(col1, col3, col2,.....col99,col100)`

```
ex names(df1)
"col1" "col2" "col3".............."col99" "col100"
```

Want to swap only "col2" and "col3", with

```
names(df1)
"col1" "col3" "col2".............."col99" "col100"
```

Comment: If you want to change the column names, `names(df1)[2:3] <- names(df1)[3:2]` or to swap the columns `df1[2:3] <- df1[3:2]`

Comment: `df = df[,c(1,3,2,4:100)]` for swapping columns

Comment: do you want to swap columns or column names?

Comment: @akrun I think the OP wanted to reorder the columns not just rename them, per the comment by mts.

Comment: I don't want to change the column name. I want to swapm positions.

Comment: In the above method I mentioned, it is just swapping the positions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1 = df1[,c(1,3,2,4:100)]
```

reorders your columns according to the permutation `c(1,3,2,4:100)`